# Python PIL is it possible to transform image based on the source shape

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am working on a tshirt mockup builder where i want to transform the image based on the source shape. Is there any PIL function that can readily do this, or should i build a custom code for the same.

eg: if i provide the source shape as below

[image]

The program should automatically transform my input image

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the poor editing I am very new to stack overflow

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your workflow, given an image, how do you want to know what kind of transformation it represents?

Comment: Maybe transformation is not the right word but i want to morp my image to fit the source shape

Comment: Have you though about how that would even be possible from an algoithmic point of view (deteached from which library has such an algorithm implemented)? Looking at your example you would want to automatically correct the orientation of the image to fit the orientation of the "source". But determining an orientation is not so trivial.

Comment: To amend to @FlyingTeller: how do you know the rectangle is not rotated *right*? Can it be mirrored? What if you input a triangle? A circle?